# how to Hide location change, but show parameters in the url in angular 9

Tags: angular, url, parameters, routes, hide

I am trying to customize my urls for SEO, I want to show the parameters passed on to route but hide the location change for the route definition as follows:

{ path:'category/:id/:name',component:CatComponent}

I have tried something like this:

this.router.navigate(['/browse/category'],{ queryParams:{ id: id, name: cat}, skipLocationChange: true });

But this not working, Pls help

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with `replaceUrl` in angular. It can replace your current state in history

reference https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationBehaviorOptions#replaceUrl

```js
this.router.navigate(['/browse/category'],{ 
    queryParams:{ id: id, name: cat},
    replaceUrl: true 
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there an option to hide only specific part of url.

Comment: Not possible to hide any url part